# Does Varaha have only one tusk(ekashringa)?

Tags: vishnu, vishnu-purana, varaha

I read somewhere that Varaha has one tusk instead of two. Is that true?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Lord Varaha have single tusk as per [Valmiki Ramayana: Yuddha Kanda: Sarga 117](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga117/yuddhasans117.htm#Verse13)

> भवान्नारायणो देवः श्रीमांश्चक्रायुधः प्रभुः || ६-११७-१३
>
> **एकशृङ्गो वराहस्त्वं** भूतभव्यसपत्नजित् |
>
> "You are the Lord Narayana himself the glorious god, who wields the discus. You are **the Divine Boar with a single tusk**, the conqueror of your past and future enemies."